# Cartesian product of two dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframe and how can I remove the similar row from the cartesian dataset

```
 **DF1:**
    Index    Name
    0       xyz
    1       abc
    2       def


    **DF2:**
    Index    Name
    0       xyz
    1       abc
    2       xyz


    **Expected Output**
    (0,0),**(0,2)**
    (1,1)
```

I want to combine only the indexes whose Name column is same however I don't want to display the repeated combination. That is, when I do cartesian index (0,2) and (2,0) will give me same result. So I want to show only one row.

**Updated:**

I already have a cartesian dataframe as input which is 
(0,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)

What I want is, from this input dataframe I want to remove the duplicate (2,0). And I have around 100 rows in the dataframe, so want to loop through as well.

Comment: What are "dataset"s? `pandas` DataFrames?

Comment: yes its dataframe, I have updated my question  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` have a single column "Name" and that "Index" is the index, and that you want a list of tuples with the matching indexes, as appear in the question, you can do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['xyz', 'abc', 'xyz']})
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on='Name', how='inner')
list_of_tuples = [tuple(item) for item in df3[['index_x', 'index_y']].values]
list_of_tuples 
# OUTPUT: [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)]
```

And if "Index" is a column name, just drop the `reset_index()` commands.

Comment: Join type is inner

Comment: @PrathikKini Did you run my code and got wrong results?

Comment: got this [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0), (1.0, 1.0), (2.0, nan)]

Comment: @PrathikKini Thank you, you are correct. I added the `how='left'` afterward, and forgot that the default for `pd.merge()` is "inner" and not "left".

Comment: I already have a cartesian dataframe as input which is (0,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)

What I want is, from this input dataframe I want to remove the duplicate (2,0). And I have around 100 rows in the dataframe, so want to loop through as well.

Comment: @user12277274 If you have a different question than what you asked, please post it as a new question with samples of existing data and expected output which are relevant for that question.